# What's the geometric interpretation of the square root of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, intuition, symmetric-matrices, visualization

**Question:**

If I have a matrix $A$, I know that its square root is a matrix that has the same eigenvectors as $A$ but its eigenvalues are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A$.

What does this mean geometrically? If we think of $A$ as a transformation of space that takes a circle of unit vectors to a rotated ellipse, what does $\sqrt{A}$ do as a transformation?

---

**Thoughts so far:**

At first, I wanted to say $\sqrt{A}$ would give us the same rotated ellipse $A$ gives us, only that the lengths of the axes of that ellipse would be the square roots of the lengths of the axes of $A$.

However, that would only work if $A$ were a symmetric matrix and its orthonormal eigenvectors are the axes of the ellipse. If $A$ isn't symmetric...

Comment: It's a matrix such that if you apply it twice, you get the same result as applying $A$ once. For example, your idea about symmetric matrices works. As another example, if $A$ is a rotation, then one choice of square root is a rotation that turns half the amount that $A$ does.

Comment: @Rahul thank you, but what about in the general case? Also, now I'm even more confused. I thought that **by definition** of the square root of a matrix, the square root of $A$ would be something that has the square roots of the eigenvalues, but now that I think about it...a rotation matrix doesn't have any eigenvectors...help!